# Simple OpenCV program in eclipse IDE with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I've done a small project using openCV for object detection. I've started porting that to android., but everything seems new.

After getting enough hands on in NDK, I'm trying to write a simple program in NDK using OpenCV to show an image in a particular directory.

`IplImage *img = cvCreateImage(size,IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
cvShowImage(blah blah)` works well in Linux. Yet, it's showing errors when the same is written in eclipse (Win platform).
`IplImage cannot be resolved. cvCreateImage cannot be resolved` etc are the errors. I've called the native function in `onCreate` method in the Java file.

Can anyone lemme know the code/process to write a simple program in opencv which shows an image.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited.! And I'm also seeking for the code.. 

cvShowImage in Linux., is it the same in NDK.?? because it's not working.

Comment: Are these errors in the compiler output - i.e. it's not building? If it compiles successfully, this could just be a Codan 'error' caused by the indexer being misconfigured. (any instances of these types will have a little red bug icon next to the line in the editor, if so)

Comment: Thanks jam.! I could fix it. It shows no compilation errors now. Probably it might be the problem with configuration.

But now it shows Unfortunately app has stopped in the emulator. FATAL Exception : main : java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. :( 

Could you please help.?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused - you've tagged this `C++`, what Java file are you talking about?

Comment: The main activity java file which we write in Android NDK.!

Comment: Hm, probably gone beyond the point at which I can help you then. I know about C++, OpenCV and Eclipse, but not Android development sorry.

Comment: Oh! Not a prob.! Thanks btw :)